# Blank labels in flow formula after packaging

Tags: managed-package, visual-workflow, customlabel

I'm working on a managed package which include a Flow.
I want some fields on this Flow to have their labels alterable so i used "Formula" inside the flow with custom labels.

This works fine on my developer org ("Please confirm the beneficiary name" is a custom label)
[image: Flow screen]

But when I package that and instal it on another org it looks like
[image: Flow target]

I think there is a problem with the namespace, but i can't change the reference to the label in the flow, (if I remove the namespace I can save but it come back automaticaly right after) [image: Formula label]

Sometimes when it come to reference a custom label in the target organization the namespace is needed, sometimes not.

Anyone has faced the same issue? How can I package a Flow with custom labels?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, as often right after posting the question i found the answer:
The labels where marked as protected...
If the checkbox is false i can see those label on my targeted org